# Vue modal diaglog with child form, submit data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

[image: Wireframe]

The black boundary is a modal component, the red is a component which has some form fields.
The buttons, save / cancel are based in the parent modal component. The form is actually 2 levels down from the modal (modal component -> child wrapper -> child form) so vuex feels a better choice.

There is also a file picker in the form.

What is the best way to get the data from the component (which could be one of a number of forms) when a user clicks the Save button.

option 1 - on each field change, call a method to update data in VUEX.
option 1a - update an object on each field change containing the whole form
option 1b - update each field individually on change.
option 2 - use refs to call some sort of submit method in child.
option 3 - a better way than 1 or 2!

**issues**

- **option 1a**, as I am passing the "data" object into vuex, when another change is made, the form is updating the v-model but it is in vuex so it is mutated outside of the mutation.
- **option 1b** seems a lot of work to get lots of field mapped into vuex.
- **option 2** since there are 2 levels of components, (which swap out) the refs seems clunky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [computed setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) to avoid mutating outside of the mutation.

```
computed: {
    fieldOne: {
        get () {
            return this.$store.state.data.fieldOne
        },
        set (newValue) {
            this.$store.commit('data/fieldOne', newValue)
        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you might use `:value` and `@input` instead of `v-model`

```
    <input
      :value="$store.state.data.fieldOne"
      @input="$store.commit('data/fieldOne', $event.target.value)"
    >
```

Comment: So that's option 1b, but if there are 20 form fields, it can be quite long.

Comment: What is the the wrapper used for?

Comment: Wrapper is used to select the correct form based upon the desired content to add, so Button A loads Content A in the modal, Button B loads Content B in the same modal, just the grandchild child component is swapped out

Comment: Why don't you integrate it as a part of the modal component? It sounds like you don't really need to make it as separate component.

Comment: Anyways, personally, I don't usually favor vuex when data is manly shared and used among 2 components only (regardless middleware components). So, I would jsut declared an object for my form in parent component, passed it as a prop ( parent -> child), and emitted any changes (child -> parent). And I'd use the 2nd approach above (:value and @input). If Wrapper can't be avoided, just use $attrs and $listeners for easier binding.

Comment: Thanks, I have dropped VUEX here as you say, the state of this is contained with this nice tree. The modal container just handles the modal element, as the wrapper is used elsewhere for the same functionality, just not in the modal. The modal now just calls the method on the wrapper, the wrapper is updated from the child component and the wrapper handles the API (since it knows which form element is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

Do you can create a internal object of the component, use him on v-model and just update vuex when click in the submit button.

Comment: so this is what I currently do. I have a "internal" object which is bound to the v-model of all form elements. The submit button is two components higher in the hierarchy, so i still either need to pass the event click down to the grandchild component, or pull the data up from the grandchild to put in vuex (which negates the benefit)

Comment: @Simon, you can use a custom v-model to the component. [This link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-v-model-support-to-custom-vue-js-components) have a good tutorial showing how to do that.

Comment: so custom v-model into the wrapper, and then another into the form component? therefore avoid vuex at all?

Comment: Yes, to simplify more, use mixins.

Comment: It actually made me think, the wrapper is responsible for selecting the form, and therefore really should be responsible for calling the right method with the form, else that selection logic is just repeated. So, simplified without vuex :)